# Can we create our own process in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to create 3 processes in 1 program to simulate deadlock. How can I define my own process? I don't want to simply open an existing process.

For example for a thread:

```
Thread X = new Thread(){ //insert whatever code here// };
```

How can we do this for a process, like:

```
Process P = new Process(){//insert different threads here//};
```

Comment: Why do you want to simulate using processes? Why not simulate it using threads?

Comment: Is it not enough to simulate a deadlock with three threads?

Comment: I can see a potentiality reason why one would need new processes to simulate deadlock - deadlock on accessing 2+ files for write at the same time, but it sounds like such behavior would be easier/more reliably obtained with proper mocks of resources than starting several processes.

Answer (score 5):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad";
            //process.StartInfo.Arguments = "filename.txt"
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: how about if I declare a method and then pass it to the process? does it work?
like Process proc = new Process(method1)?

Comment: @Optional  I don't know for sure, but I don't think that c# `Process` supports that.

Comment: ahh thanks, cu you can do that with a thread.
but what i'm doing is that creating objects and locking them to simulate deadlock. so I'd like to write my own process. not jus launch an existing one

Answer (score 2):

Processes come from executable files.

You can write `Process.Start(@"C:\Something.exe")`.

Comment: Processes comes from the operating system and are sometimes created from exe files.  ; )

Answer (score 0):

You probably looking for [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92699yzt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (either static or instance method) - which will create new process by launching executable of your choice.

If you looking for implementation of [fork from Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28Unix%29) you can't really do that in .Net to my knowledge.

Comment: Of course you can always start another instance of "yourself" by dynamically fetching the path of the executable you're running, and you can use command line arguments to indicate what is a user execution and what is a programmatic execution.

Comment: @Servy, yes, but it is nowhere close to fork (also fork is not likley what OP wants). Your suggestion will allow good approximation of sample in the question.

Comment: Fork isn't supported by Windows at all, due to the way how dlls are loaded, you only can start processes from executable images. Cygwin goes to great pains to emulate fork but can't get it always right when third party dlls (like antivirus software) force themselves into the process.

Answer (score 0):

Code in one process cannot be executed in another process. You need some form of inter-process communication, or remote procedure call.